# How to disable resizeing of a window with autohotkey?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I wrote a script with autohotkey, that keeps the clicked window always on top

```
~MButton::
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
MouseGetPos, ClickX, ClickY, WindowUnderMouseID
WinActivate, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouseID%
WinGetClass, class, A
MouseGetPos, ClickX, ClickY, WindowUnderMouseID
WinGetPos, x, y, w, h, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouseID%

; check if title bar, with an exception for Firefox with tabs in title bar that can be middle-clicked to close
if (ClickX < w and ClickY < 24 and ClickY > 0 and ClickX > 0 and class != "MozillaWindowClass")
{
    WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Toggle, A
}
Return
```

Now I want to modify this script to disable the possibility of the window to be resized. I found something with `Gui, -resize` but I don't see how this would help. Replacing the AlwaysOnTop with resize does not work (Parameter #1 is invalid).

How can I achieve the desired funktionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search, I found the following line of code that disables the resize

```
WinSet, Style, -0x40000, A
```

In your case, you would swap out `A` for your `%WindowUnderMouseID%`

Comment: This works but feels a bit awkward and the window can be resized and pops back to the original size after a second (this is anoying if the content of the window takes some time to be drawn). Isn't there a way to disable the resize altogether?

Comment: Thanks, that works way better (not if I replace the A though).